# how to send data from NodeJs to react-admin

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-admin

I currently have a react native app with NodeJS as my backend, Sequilize as my ORM and postgres as my database. Everything in terms of API is working as required but now i want to create an admin panel to view all the data on.

I kept researched online and found instead of developing an admin panel from scratch i can use react-admin to help me out.

I followed all the instructions on the react-admin documentation and reached a conclusion that everything happens in the DataProvider.

My problem is how do i go about and accomplish it?

Comment: Maybe read the doc? https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviderWriting.html